# Share ADSL connection and control bandwidth

Tags: networking, router, bandwidth

As the title mentions, I need to split up my ADSL Internet to share with a neighbour, and I want to cap their bandwidth use.

I have two different routers that I can use if it helps:

- Asus dsl n10e
- Linksys wag120n

I can not find any option in either router settings that can specify a bandwidth limit, is it possible?

Or is there another way I can use these two routers to limit their bandwidth use?

Comment: Can you dedicate one of the routers for your neighbour?  If so, do they need to be on the same network as you or can you be completely separate?

Comment: yes it could be separated, then ?

Comment: Oh wait, you have a single ADSL connection, and want to use two routers to control bandwidth?  So the question isn't so much about the routers, but about how to share ADSL in such a way that you can limit your neighbours usage?  Could you update the question with the router models you have?

Comment: yes that is the point ,sharing single ADSL via two routers if possible,I will OK

Comment: I have updated your question to reflect what you are asking.  Can you check my understanding is correct?

Comment: OK, that's right - sorry if I was unclear-
I hope that you have a solution or some clues out there -- I have to leave now I will check it tomorrow thanks--

Comment: Does DD-WRT or OpenWRT work on either of those routers ? That could be an option.

Comment: Oops, it seems nor of them is supported :( @Lawrence, then no way ?

Comment: You can build a Linux server as a router and then use those 2 routers as Wireless Access Points rather than routers. With 3 network cards in the Linux server, you can then control bandwidth that way

Comment: Oh no, this is the worst choice I supposed, it is really hard somehow to build a server by me....no free of charge solution around ?

Comment: If I decided to buy new router ,would you suggest some models/brands which may support sharing/dividing bandwidth issue ??